# finding apache build options

Tags: apache

I need to rebuild an apache server, but the original source is no longer available. Is there any way ( command line switch to httpd? ) to get the build options which were originally used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try -V which "Print the version and build parameters of httpd, and then exit."

```
httpd -V
```

Also, you can see the options for httpd via:

```
httpd -h
```

Comment: httpd -V optput seems nothing like ./configure options.

Answer (score 5):

I found previous configure options in the build directory of apache root.

I'm a Centos 5/6 user.

Apache ver. is 2.2.27.

apachedir/build/config.nice

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# Created by configure

"./configure" \
"--prefix=/usr/local/apache2" \
"--enable-so" \
"--enable-mods-shared=most" \
"--enable-ssl" \
"--with-mpm=worker" \
"--enable-cgi" \
"$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-compiled apache 2.4.3 recently and change the MPM from worker to prefork, what you have to do if you still keep your original compiled directory without ran "make distclean" (if you ran "make clean" it still OK). You can use the SAME configure option to re-configure by exec ./config.status or you can find and copy './configure' from ./config.status (yes, all the original options that you used to run configure still there).

Here is part of my config.status...

```
if $ac_cs_silent; then
  exec 6>/dev/null
  ac_configure_extra_args="$ac_configure_extra_args --silent"
fi

if $ac_cs_recheck; then
  set X /bin/sh **'./configure'  '--enable-file-cache' '--enable-cache' '--enable-disk-cache' '--enable-mem-cache' '--enable-deflate' '--enable-expires' '--enable-headers' '--enable-usertrack' '--enable-cgi' '--enable-vhost-alias' '--enable-rewrite' '--enable-so' '--with-apr=/usr/local/apache/' '--with-apr-util=/usr/local/apache/' '--prefix=/usr/local/apache' '--with-mpm=worker' '--with-mysql=/var/lib/mysql' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' '--enable-mods-shared=most' '--enable-ssl' 'CFLAGS=-Wall -O3 -ffast-math -frename-registers -mtune=corei7-avx' '--enable-modules=all' '--enable-proxy' '--enable-proxy-fcgi'** $ac_configure_extra_args --no-create --no-recursion
  shift
  $as_echo "running CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/sh $*" >&6
  CONFIG_SHELL='/bin/sh'
  export CONFIG_SHELL
  exec "$@"
fi
```